# Spring Integration Proxy Settings using HttpCllient

Tags: http, proxy, spring-integration

I am using spring integration 4.1.2 (ws and core) trying to use `HTTPClient` (apache) on transport.

I thought that following some reading and configuring the `messageSender` and `messageFactory` Spring would use the settings configured on XML (application context) but the configuration is not working as expected.

My xml to configure the `HttpClient` follows:

```
   <bean id="requestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig" factory-method="custom">
            <property name="socketTimeout" value="${saog.connection.timeout}" /> 
            <property name="connectTimeout" value="${saog.connection.timeout}" /> 
        </bean>

    <bean id="requestConfig" factory-bean="requestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="httpHostProxy" class="org.apache.http.HttpHost">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="10.1.6.91" ></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg  index="1" value="80"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!--  <property name="defaultHeaders" ref="defaultHeaders"></property> -->
    <bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" factory-method="create">
        <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="requestConfig" />
        <property name="proxy" ref="httpHostProxy"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="httpClient" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />

    <bean id="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
    </bean>     

    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
        <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
        <property name="messageSender" ref="defaultMessageSender" />
    </bean>
```

From here using the ws:outbound-gateway i am facing some problems with configuration:

I made a service with the following parameter as configuration:

```
    <ws:outbound-gateway
        uri="${server.address}/${endpoint}"
        interceptor="anintercerptor"
        message-factory="messageFactory"  message-sender="defaultMessageSender">
        <ws:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <ref bean="retryAdvice" />
        </ws:request-handler-advice-chain>          
    </ws:outbound-gateway>
```

But when I'm debugging the proxy is not being set (but the timeout it is and the timeout is in the same bean config). and the `ApplicationServer` is throwing an exception and by my surprise the transport (http) is the JavaNative transport.

A sample of the error follow bellow:

```
java.io.IOException:
                        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:412)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:271)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:258)
         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:376)
         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
         at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:437)
         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:551)
         at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.<init>(c.java:143)
         at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.a(c.java:67)
         at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.getNewHttpClient(d.java:55)
         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:935)
         at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:10)
         at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1043)
         at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:62)
         at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection.getRequestOutputStream(HttpUrlConnection.java:85)
         at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractSenderConnection$RequestTransportOutputStream.createOutputStream(AbstractSenderConnection.java:106)
         at org.springframework.ws.transport.TransportOutputStream.getOutputStream(TransportOutputStream.java:41)
         at org.springframework.ws.transport.TransportOutputStream.write(TransportOutputStream.java:64)
         at com.ibm.ws.webservices.utils.LowFlushFilter.write(LowFlushFilter.java:70)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:355)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:425)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:429)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:175)
         at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:274)
         at com.ibm.ws.webservices.utils.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:318)
         at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.SOAPPart.writeTo(SOAPPart.java:841)
         at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.Message.writeTo(Message.java:669)
         at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.writeTo(SaajSoapMessage.java:275)
         at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:46)
         at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:654)
         at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:603)
         at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
         at org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:93)
         at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:188)
         at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessa
```

And clue how to solve the Proxy config setting using the `HttpClient` on SpringIntegration?

Regards.

Jose Carlos Canova.

Comment: Everything looks good from the config perspective and we really have a test to be sure that `message-sender` injection works well: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ws/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ws/config/UriVariableTests-context.xml. So, not sure how to help you. Maybe you can debug your application and check what's going on since the `SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle()` code...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my guess is the WebSphere SAAJ, it is not an issue, but obligates me to alter the context using an interceptor.